# Changing the Flash Ratio as an input variable in Sekonic light meters

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, light-meter

I just got a `Sekonic` light meter `( 478 DR )` and also have some flashes and `PocketWizard` radio triggers. The radio triggers are not `TTL` based. 
When I fire the flash with the Sekonic light meter, it tells me some values including the "**ratio**" of the flash to the ambient light at the corner of the screen.
My question is that is it possible I can tell the light meter that for example I want 30% ratio contribution from flash light and it tell me the other values? And if it is not possible then how do I achieve that? Be playing around with reducing the flash power until the meter says Ok now 30% is coming from flash?

Answer (score 3):

That's a very nice feature, in that if you find a particular mix of fill flash that you think looks natural, you can recreate it any time.  But you'll have to use trial and error to get the ratio you're looking for, the meter won't let you set it as a target. If the ratio is higher than you want, you could lower the shutter speed a few stops to let in more ambient.  Or you could lower the flash output.